# Does Google Chrome ARC support URL Schemes?

Tags: url-scheme, google-chrome-arc

Google just [released ARC](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc) to run Android apps on PCs.
Does ARC support URL Schemes (e.g.; `example://pass?var=hello`) to launch and pass data from the Chrome browser to an ARC Android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, ARC does not support this type of URI based intent.  ARC is limited by what is possible on the [Chrome App platform](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index), and this functionality is not exposed to Chrome Apps currently.

The only way to launch your app based on an intent in ARC is to register an intent-filter for a [MIME type or file pattern](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Storage) for the [ACTION_SEND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) or [ACTION_VIEW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) intent: